# How to construct HDFS's Path from properties in jar?

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark

I have a small spark program use Scala and I want package it into a executable fat-jar,the configurations set in file:`src/main/resource/localconfig.properties`, so I new an instance of `org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path(String pathString)` in `src/main/scala/com.let.App`:

```
val Path = new Path("localconfig.properties")
```

the problem is it can run on IDEA but failed when package in jar and run with `java -jar myapp.jar`,prompt: file cannot found.

I extract the jar and the properties file is in the root folder: myapp, also I have tried `Path("resources/localconfig.properties")` and it doesn't work too.

how can I set right path for Path in a executable jar?

It is windows environment, I read the Path() method it seems relate to OS but still I have no idea how to use the constructor.

Comment: Object "fs.Path" is worked with HDFS. On Windows env, HDFS and local directory are the same. But on Hadoop env they are different. Guess, config file can be read as simple File(not "fs.Path"). Or config file can be put on HDFS.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting [Path(String pathString)](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/Path.html#Path-java.lang.String-):

> Construct a path from a String. Path strings are URIs, but with unescaped elements and some additional normalization.

That means that the `pathString` (e.g. `localconfig.properties` in your example) should be available on the file system which is clearly not the case. The file is inside the jar file so you should ask JVM to give you the file.

That's where you should use Hadoop HDFS's [Path(URI aUri)](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/Path.html#Path-java.net.URI-) and Java's [ClassLoader.getResource](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResource-java.lang.String-) method.

```
$ jar cvf /tmp/hello.jar hello.xml

$ jar -tf /tmp/hello.jar
META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
hello.xml

// start spark-shell with the jar on the CLASSPATH
// that should be exactly your case where your jar is on CLASSPATH
// with the file you want to use to construct Path inside

$ ./bin/spark-shell --jars /tmp/hello.jar

scala> this.getClass.getResource("/hello.xml")
res0: java.net.URL = jar:file:/tmp/hello.jar!/hello.xml

// Convert URL to URI that Path supports
scala> this.getClass.getResource("/hello.xml").toURI
res1: java.net.URI = jar:file:/tmp/hello.jar!/hello.xml

scala> import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path

scala> new Path(this.getClass.getResource("/hello.xml").toURI)
res3: org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path = jar:
```

I however don't know whether constructing `Path` like this is supported or not.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is still open, but I ran into this problem trying to access reference data for a Spark application.  Jacek's answer is close, but it runs into a common hadoop issue where paths cannot handle multiple `:` delimited schemes, so `jar:file:` gets mapped to just `jar:` under a `hadoop.fs.Path`. This often manifests itself as an error about Relative Paths.

The only workaround that I found was to access the jar resource as an `InputStream`, then copy that `InputStream` to a temporary (local) file and load it from there.  This is not super efficient and not particularly pretty, but it seems to work (I'm sure others will run into write permissions issues, but I haven't yet).

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils

val resourceName: String = "myResource.tsv"
val inputStream: InputStream = YourClass.getClass.getResourceAsStream(resourceName)
val tmpDir: String = FileUtils.getTempDirectoryPath // You need write permissions here
val outPath: java.nio.file.Path = java.nio.file.Paths.get(tmpDir, resourceName)
val outUriString: String = outPath.toUri.toString // Need full URI
val java.nio.file.Files.copy(inputStream, outPath)  // Signature requires (InputStream, Path)
new java.io.File(outUriString).deleteOnExit() // Delete temp file after execution

/* You should be able to access the local file now, e.g. */
val data = spark.read.csv(outUriString)
```